# I am trying to access the bedroom attribute from the dataframe but unable to do so, even though the attribute exists

Tags: pandas

I am reading a csv file which gives me a dataframe but unable to access any attributes of it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtzaR.png)

I did try doing df['bedroom'] but it gave a issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKW00.png)

I am new to python and the field of datascience and it might be a rookie mistake